# Create an observable that repeatedly calls a method

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I would like to repeatedly get a properties value and assign it to another property, but I don't have a handle on Rx's `Observable` creation quite yet. How do I create and subscribe to an observable that just constantly reads a property (maybe on a timer or with throttling)?

Comment: Does the object that owns the property implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` by any chance? That would be a cleaner way of solving this.

Comment: @Richard No, it doesn't implement INPC. I thought about that, but it's not worth introducing just to get this behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the static `Interval` operator to emit a value repeatedly on a given time span and then use a `Select` opertor to transform it to the property value on the object you wish to poll.

```
var objectIWantToPoll = new MyObject(); 
var objectIWantToSetPropertyOn = new MyObject();


var polledValues =  Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) 
   .Select(_ => objectIWantToPoll.SomeProperty);

polledValues.Subscribe(propertyValue => 
   objectIWantToSetPropertyOn.SomeProperty = propertyValue));
```

Comment: Ah, so that's how you use the `Interval` method.

Comment: You might want to add DistinctUntilChanged to avoid unnecessary notifications

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IObservable<long> CreateObservableTimerWithAction(this Action actionT, int timeSpan, Control control)
    {
        var obs = Observable.Create<long>(
             observer =>
             {
                 Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeSpan))
.DistinctUntilChanged(fg =>control.Text ).Subscribe(l => actionT());
                 return Disposable.Empty;
             });

        return obs;
    }
```

0r :

```
public static IObservable<long> CreateObservableTimer<T>(this Action actionT,int timeSpan)
    {
       var obs= Observable.Create<long>(
            observer =>
            { 
                Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeSpan))
.DistinctUntilChanged().Subscribe(l => actionT());
                return Disposable.Empty;
            });
        return obs;
    }
```

I use this quite often , to have timed methods go at certain time , until i dispose of them (obs.Dispose() )..

CreateObservableTimer(() => CheckForDequeues(1),500);

I actually sometimes use the long, but most of the times , not...

Even use this helper to check Schedulers in a priority queue, so could be used to

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are essentially asking for a polling implementation where some component polls for changed values. Observables are typically for reacting to objects pushed to you (through events/observables/etc) rather than pulling for values. Perhaps just setting up a background process on a timer and operating on that timer's Tick would be sufficient for your case. Observable.Interval behaves similarly as James Hay mentioned. Beware that Observable.Interval will move your execution context off of the dispatcher thread.

Why are you trying to shoehorn Rx into your polling implementation? Do you have other observable data sources that you are trying to synchronize here?

Comment: I understand that rx is for 'push' rather than 'pull', but it seems easier to use for polling than a timer. Perhaps I should look at it the other way around, though - I could return an Observable rather than the particular property from the secondary object.